# Salesforce Org UI is changed

Tags: force.com

After performing the Burp Security scanner process my Salesforce developer Org UI was changed.

[image]

Please help me how to change it to original Ui of the salesforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Setup -> Customize -> User Interface ->** check **Enable New User Interface Theme**